# Парсинг JavaScript-кода ECMA 6 на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Нужно распарсить (а желательно, выполнить) JavaScript-код на Python.
В нём есть стрелочные функции, поэтому [Js2Py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py) абсолютно не подходит.

Пробовал регулярными выражениями, одна из попыток: https://regexr.com/6djpm
Корректно ими менять `a => a*2` на `function(a){return a*2}` не получается.

В общем, нужна либо другая библиотека, либо нормальный regexp.

Comment: А для чего это нужно? :) Я бы мб завел браузер из Qt, типа QWebEngine* и в его рамках выполнял код, возвращая результат в питон

Comment: @gil9red, мысль такая была, но... не могли бы Вы дать, например, ссылки на модули, реализующие браузерный парсер без GUI? И насколько это будет долго выполняться?  
Цель: есть обфусцированный код, в котором содержится токен для Ajax-запросов. Вот я его и пытаюсь вытащить для выполнения запросов к приватному API. GH: https://github.com/DarkCat09/python-aternos

Comment: Я бы сразу сделал на selenium'е, тем более если парсер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Накидал решение](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/004c6fe4e3916ce4f3043e464a790f553911f3e7/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/run_js.py) для выполнения `javascript` и получения результат, используя [QWebEnginePage.runJavaScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#runJavaScript-2)

Установка PyQt5:

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Код:

```py
from typing import Any

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage


app = QApplication([])


def run_js(code: str) -> Any:
    result: Any = None
    callback_finished = False

    def _callback(v):
        nonlocal result, callback_finished
        result = v
        callback_finished = True

    page = QWebEnginePage()
    page.runJavaScript(code, _callback)

    while not callback_finished:
        QApplication.processEvents()

    return result
```

Тест:

```py
print(run_js("2+2"))
print(run_js("let f = a => a*2; f(10)"))
print(run_js("""
    let f = a => a*2;
    f(10);
"""))
print(run_js("""
    function f(a) {
        return a * 2;
    }
    f(10);
"""))
```

Результат:

```
4
20
20
20
```

Comment: Во, спасибо, для моего проекта подходит. А нет ли случаем отдельного модуля такого WebEngine, чтобы не тянуть весь фреймворк?

Comment: @Andrey, неа. Там зависимости к другим библиотекам Qt. Проще искать решение через selenium, но там помимо самого селениума нужно на компе ставить браузер и драйвер к нему

Answer (score 0):

Можно, конечно, и регуляркой попробовать. Но тут нужно как можно больше примеров и то результат не гарантирован :)

Например:

```py
text = 'a => a*2'
m = re.search('(.+?)=>(.+)', text)
if m:
    text = 'function(%s){return %s}' % (m.group(1), m.group(2))

print(text)
# function(a ){return  a*2}
```